# Cortana/Bot/LUIS Caching Issues

Tags: caching, botframework, azure-language-understanding, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

Was trying to get LUIS to recognize some asset names which are a bit complex via voice. Using an entity list was working well with a small test of about 10 but then loaded around 10,000 which caused Cortana to hang up and not listen anymore. After deleting the list and rebuilding the small one it doesn't work the same though. Cortana/LUIS seems to grab remnants of something... it keeps interpreting some mysterious value “10r4” like it is in the list or utterance but is nowhere to be found.

1. Any idea where these new mysterious voice matches might be coming from? Is there some caching that can be cleared on the Cortana, LUIS and/or Bot side? Tried clearing Cortana's notebook data in my MSA.
2. Similarly, the bot channels seem to cache images too. I swapped a few hero card images out but it keeps showing the old ones. Had to change the file names to get the new ones to show. Not sure where those are being cached either.

I feel like I am missing something simple here. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: one thing you can try is using the `/deleteprofile` command.  [More info on that here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/101).  This is worth a shot at the least.

Comment: @JasonSowers tried that too, sorry, forgot to mention... didn't help unfortunately. Thanks though

Comment: Have you tried disabling and then re-enabling speech recognition priming, by unchecking the box associated with the LUIS app in the Bot Framework developer portal, saving, and then re-checking it later?

Comment: The LUIS and Speech engineering teams are interested in resolving your issue. Can you contact the LUIS support team by using the **Support** link in the top navigation bar of the UI at www.luis.ai and indicate that you were having difficulty with speech recognition priming?

Comment: @DeniseMak re-enabling the speech recognition priming did clear up those mysterious words. Thanks for suggesting that. I guess this option needs to be toggled from time to time to get the bot to pick up changes? Now not sure why it doesn't seem to recognize many other list entities it had before and still should be :(. Thanks again!

Comment: @Cood did you ever get your list entity working again? Can you post the JSON for your LUIS app? I can try to repro the problem.

Comment: @DeniseMak Turning the priming on and off the first time did clear up the initial issue. Was excited to know this trick. But now in later changes to entities the trick no longer works :(. Makes it hard to test. Here is the LUIS JSON (some items removed for privacy): https://www.dropbox.com/s/moexjpqhajk3gnl/Test%20Bot.json?dl=0